# AJAX commenting in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm trying to get AJAX commenting working in WordPress. So far I have written a PHP handler and a script.

My script (modified from [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/ajaxify-wordpress-comments/)):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var commentform = $('#commentform');
    commentform.prepend('<div id="comment-status"></div>');
    var statusdiv = $('#comment-status'); 

    commentform.submit(function(){
        //serialize and store form data in a variable
        var data=commentform.serialize();
        //Add a status message
        statusdiv.html('<p>Processing...</p>');
        //Extract action URL from commentform
        var formurl=commentform.attr('action');
        //Post Form with data
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: formurl,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: data,
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, errorThrown)
                {
                    statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error" >Oops, an error occured</p>');
                },
            success: function(data)
                {
                    statusdiv.html(data);
                    $('#commentform #comment').val('');
                }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

My PHP handler:

```
function ajaxify_comments( $comment_ID, $comment_status ) {

    $comment = get_comment( $comment_ID );

    $response = $comment->comment_content;
    echo json_encode( $response );

    die();
}
add_action( 'comment_post', 'ajaxify_comments', 20, 2 );
```

My PHP handler, `ajaxify_comments()`, is hooked to `comment_post` which fires immediately after the comment is saved to the database. The function gets the comment text and returns a response (the comment text) to my AJAX script. If everything is successful, the comment text is displayed on screen. If unsuccessful, an error message is displayed.

**My problem**

If I submit a comment, the comment is saved to the database and the comment text is displayed on screen. This bit works! My problem is if I make a second comment without refreshing the page - I always get "Oops, an error occurred". What am I doing wrong?

**Update**

After @adeneo's suggestion to use the WordPress built in AJAX hooks I have come up with a new script and PHP handler...

Script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var path = ac.path;
    var security = ac.security;
    var ajax_url = ac.ajax_url;

    var commentform = $('#commentform');
    commentform.prepend('<div id="comment-status"></div>');
    var statusdiv = $('#comment-status');

    commentform.submit(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_url,
            dataType: 'JSON',
            data: {
                'action': 'ac',
                'security': security
            },
            success:function(data) {
                statusdiv.html(data);
                $('#commentform #comment').val('');
            },
            error: function(data){
                statusdiv.html('<p class="ajax-error">Oops, an AJAX error occured</p>');
            }
        });
        return false;

    });
});
```

PHP handler

```
function ajaxify_comments() {

    check_ajax_referer( 'ajax_ac_nonce', 'security' );

    $response = 'blah';
    echo json_encode( $response );

    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_ac', 'ajaxify_comments' );
```

For completeness it is worth letting you know that I also have:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'ac-script', plugins_url( '/js/script.js', __FILE__ ), array( 'jquery' ), 1.0, true );
        $path = get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' );

        // set the nonce security check
        $ajax_nonce = wp_create_nonce( 'ajax_ac_nonce' );

        wp_localize_script(
            'ac-script',
            'ac',
            array(
                'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
                'path'  => $path,
                'security' => $ajax_nonce,
            )
        );
```

**My question now becomes:** How do I make the submitted comment data available to my PHP handler? I guessing I'll need to manually save the comment data to the database? I need this data available in my PHP function first but not sure how to do that?

Comment: Not really an answer, but you should be using the built in ajax hooks, as wordpress has a dedicated URL and hook for ajax requests.

Comment: Are you using akismet?

Comment: @adeneo not sure how I'd do that?

Comment: @enapupe I know I need to use a WP nonce. Is that why you ask?

Comment: You don't *have* to use a nonce, but you should, you can see how ajax is used in wordpress plugins in the [**codex**](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins), and that's pretty much how you should do it as it's generally easier than rolling your own.

Comment: @adeneo ah yes, I see. Thanks for the link - i'll check it out

Comment: Hi @adeneo I've had a read up on the built-in AJAX hooks. I was aware of them but didn't think of using them so thanks for the nudge in the right direction. So, in my PHP handler, will I have to manually save the comment data to the database? I'm guessing I will have to?

Comment: Please see my updated question - I'm now using the built-in hooks as you can see from my new script and PHP handler. My question now becomes: How do I made the submitted comment data available to my PHP handler function?

Comment: Think I've answered my question. Doing something like var text = $('#commentform #comment').val(); after form submit then passing the value to my PHP handler which adds the comment to the database using wp_new_comment() - is this the best way to do it?